# Filtering data from database in django

Tags: django

I need to select a specific category from appointments to display on my table. I am only displaying all the records from the database. I have 3 categories; plumbing, electrical and cleaning

{% for appointment in appointments %}

```
                    <td>{{appointment.worker}}</td>
                    <td>{{appointment.category}}</td>
                    <td>{{appointment.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>{{appointment.status}}</td>
                    

                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_appointment' appointment.id %}">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Here are the views

@login_required(login_url='login')
def user(request):

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.all()
clients = Client.objects.all()

total_appointments = appointments.count()
delivered = appointments.filter(status='Delivered').count()
pending = appointments.filter(status='Pending').count()

context = {'appointments': appointments, 'clients': clients,
           'total_appointments': total_appointments, 'delivered':  delivered, 'pending ': pending}

return render(request, 'users/user.html', context)
```

Comment: Could you please post, views related code. If you want to display specific category related data, then we can filter it out in views.

Comment: Where you define **appointments** variable?

Comment: I have a model called Appointment that contains all the data

Answer (score 0):

`appointments` is a queryset against a model. At present, it's specifying all Appointment objects. In your view, change it to something like

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter( category='plumbing' )
```

(the exact filter will depend on the Appointment model and what you use to specify this category).

More generally you might use a variable to specify the category rather than the constant `'plumbing'`, for example passed through a category_list URL:

```
path( 'category_list/<str:category>', view, name='category_list'),
```

Comment: Thanks. It has worked, I appreciate